# Automatically compute r[1] = r1; r[2] = r2; …

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have three variables like this,

```
r1 = 4;
r2 = 3;
r3 = 1;
```

and I want to insert them into a function use them in a function definition like so:

```
f[n_] := r[n] + r[n-1]
```

So I need to have a function that just duplicates the variable, something like:

```
r[1] = r1 = 4;
r[2] = r2 = 3;
r[3] = r3 = 1;
```

Firstly, I thought of doing

```
r[n_] := r[n]
```

but that doesn't make much sense.

---

I was wondering if there is some nice way to do this?

Comment: Try: `r[n_] := Symbol["r" <> ToString[n]]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
r[n_] := Symbol["r" <> ToString[n]]
```

Then:

```
r[1]
```

gives

> r1

Comment: But is r[1]=r1=4 true?

Comment: @Arcotick `r[1] == r1 == 4` will evaluate to `True`

Comment: +1 for correctly using `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression`.

Comment: To @Mr.Wizard, why not `ToExpression`? I thought the effect is the same...

Comment: @Leo The effect can be the same, but `ToExpression` will also evaluate arbitrary code which could result in strange errors, or in the case of library code malicious abuse.  `Symbol` is simply better suited yet often overlooked.  Evaluation is somewhat different as well (as shown by `Trace`) but usually not significant.

Comment: Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yet `Symbol` is the weirdest function name: `x[[x = 0; "x" // Part[[x]]]]` -> `Symbol` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The method below sets the actual values to `r`:-

```
r1 = 4;
r2 = 3;
r3 = 1;

Clear[r, f, g];

f = Function[{rn},
   r[ToExpression@StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated[rn], 1]],
   {HoldFirst}];

g = Function[{rf}, Evaluate[f[rf]] = rf, {HoldFirst, Listable}];

g[{r1, r2, r3}]
```

> {4, 3, 1}

```
r[1] == r1
```

> True