# Iteration variable in variable

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible to create following list by some sort of iteration?

```
{a1,a2,a3,...,a100}
```

I cannot think of any way to append a to

```
Range[100]
```

Comment: `Symbol["a" <> #] & /@ IntegerString[Range[100]]`.

Comment: So easy to answer and not so easy to google... Thanks

Comment: Many duplicates: [(6623)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6623/121),
[(13146)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13146/121),
[(16793)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16793/121),
[(20160)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20160/121),
[(20412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121),
[(30863)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30863/121),
[(33184)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33184/121),
[(36886)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36886/121),
[(38749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38749/121)

Comment: Also related: [(197)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197/121),
[(783)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.M. pointed out we should look in `Symbol[ ]` direction. Here is the modification that makes his/her useful  comment work.

```
Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[100]
```